# How to call a function after mouseup (mouse release) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, mouseup

[image]I am trying to call a function after I release the mouse button, the function I am trying to call it after mouseup event is going to update the localstorage. The problem is I can see the console.log but it doesn't make any changes on locolstorage.

**HTML**

```
 <li class="item ui-state-default " draggable="true" id="${id}" onmouseup="mouseUp()">
     <p class="text" >${tileName}</p>
                 
       <span class="close" tile="delete" id="${id}">&times;</span>
   </li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function saveOrder() {

    const char = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
    const num = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    const charArray = jQuery.makeArray(char);
    const numArray = jQuery.makeArray(num);

    nameArray = charArray.map(e => e.innerText);
    idArray = numArray.map(e => e.id)

    let saveIt = nameArray.map((i, idx) => ({
      name: i,
      id: +idArray[idx],
      trash: false
    }));


    localStorage.setItem('TILES', JSON.stringify(saveIt));
  }

function mouseUp() {
  saveOrder()
  console.log("mouseUP function called!")
}
```

Comment: Why have you nested that `saveOrder` function in the `mouseUp` function like that?

Comment: The code seems executes fine, put a `console.log` within the nested function and you'll find this. The `onmouseup` event is working as intended, the error must come from your `localstorage` code. Also, you might want to consider removing that nested function.

Comment: @Polymer about your comment to the deleted answer. You should consider not linking to w3schools as a reference. While they aren't as bad as they use to be they are still full of inaccuracies, contain bad coding styles/suggestions and there are various places where they suggest using deprecated APIs without mentioning that they are deprecated.

Comment: @t.niese completely agree, however it was the first quick example I could find. Will consider not using them next time!

Comment: Could it be that you try to use `localStorage` on an online tool like jsfiddle, codepen, … ?

Comment: An additional note: to convert the result of `document.querySelectorAll` to an array you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), there is no need to use a library like jQuery for that.

Comment: Yes you are right I shouldn't have to nest to function actually I did use untested but it still not working it works when I release the mouse on elements two times. when I move it once and refresh the browser it doesn't save the position in localstorage I add a screen record please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Based on the description you added it is likely that at elements didn't change their position at the moment when `mouseup` is triggered, but at a later point in time. Without knowing how the drag and drop is implemented it is hard to tell how to solve it. But that `setItem` works for every `mouseup` , but `saveIt` is not what you expect it should be.

Comment: Drag and drop is working with the jQuery library https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: I haven't used jquery for a while. But based on the docs I would guess that you should listen for the [`update`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event, and do your local storage update there.

Comment: I found the solution :) it is related to the event attribute in HTML code instead of **`onmouseup`** I should have used **`onmouseleave`**.

Comment: @MohammadKhavari while I assume that `onmouseleave` will work reliable, I would consider that as a workaround. You still should consider to used the event that is intended for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be somewhere else in your code. I ran this in jsFiddle
and it works. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1jnusrh/3/)

```js
function mouseUp() {

  function saveOrder() {

    const char = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
    const num = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    const charArray = jQuery.makeArray(char);
    const numArray = jQuery.makeArray(num);

    nameArray = charArray.map(e => e.innerText);
    idArray = numArray.map(e => e.id)

    let saveIt = nameArray.map((i, idx) => ({
      name: i,
      id: +idArray[idx],
      trash: false
    }));
    
    localStorage.setItem('TILES', JSON.stringify(saveIt));
  }
  saveOrder()
  console.log("mouseUP function called!")
  
  // Added lines
  const tiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TILES'))
  console.log({tiles}) // console.log shows saved TILES
}
```

Comment: It is working just when I release the mouse button twice. see the screen record above.